# Running application while idle for Android

Tags: java, android, url, background

I was wondering if there is a way to keep running my application (which basically just refreshes a URL every X seconds) even when the phone idles/locks? (when the screen turns off).  I'm currently using a WebView to load the URL, and a Runnable to reload it.

When I tried using a service, it keeps giving me a problem - webview cannot be resolved.  I looked it up, and I couldn't get it fixed.

I would also like to know if there is a way to browse a URL in the background.  Basically, browsing a URL without showing the browser :D

Any help would be much appreciated!!!
Sorry if these questions are dumb, I've only started Android programming for a few days.

Comment: why don't you just refresh the webview on resume ??

Comment: I would like it to refresh even during idle/lock, I'm trying to invoke something in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a webview to poke web server, unless you like to display results imeediately. 
You can use built in http client for this purpose ( works from service and does not vae user interfce)

Comment: Could you please show how I would do this? ~ the Http part.  Would the server see it the same as viewing the content through a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Timer` task will solve your problem.

```
 Timer timer=new Timer();
timer.schedule(new DelayedTask(),1, 1000);// it will repeat within 1000ms
private class DelayedTask extends TimerTask
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                webview.loadUrl(url);
            } 
        });


    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();
}
```